# Input data to Simulink from workspace

Tags: matlab, simulink

Hello anyone does know? I have data(myData) from matlab workspace. And in matlab simulink I have to do control system with regulator.First how to put data(myData) to simulink model input,and I want to show in graph two value(myData and regulator).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `From Workspace` block to read the data( lets say **simin**  ) from the worspace.

The variable **simin** should a structure with following fields:

- signals :

  - values : A column vector representing data.
  - Description : A string describing the data (can be empty)
- time :  The time stamp, Its a column vector, with dimension same as that of the signals field ( can be empty as well)

That's for importing data into Simulink. For exporting the data, you can use the **To Workspace** block in the Simulink library.

Notice, that the output will also be a structure unless, you specify in the properties of the **To Workspace** to be an array.

You can refer to the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/toworkspace.html)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for answers. And do you know how to write in .m file instead of simulink?

Comment: You can access the value in the vector form using `simout.signals.value` Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: I don`t understand.Problem like this, I have data to input.But how to put from workspace.My data was <1000,1>.How to put these data instead of integrator,Constant,etc.Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simulink block "From Workspace". Search in the simulink library if required.

Your data from the workspace must have at least 2 columns, i.e.
1. Time stamp 
2. Signal
Both column vectors must have with the same dimension if not error message will pop out.

For example in the workspace

A<5x2 doubles>

A = [ 14.3 0.5 ;14.2 0.48; 14.1 0.44; 14.1 0.5; 14.6 0.6];

Then, in Simulink , using the From Workspace, insert [A] in the Data field as shown in the examples. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html

Finally Run your simulink model !
Have Fun

¬atck