# Workspace struct array input to Simulink M file S function

Tags: matlab, struct, simulink

I would like my Simulink Level 2 S function to sequentially run a series of test cases. Each test case populates a struct containing multiple numerical arrays. 
I am currently trying to achieve the above in two steps:

- Step 1: generate test cases using a M file, save to Workspace as an array of structs
- Step 2: read the array of structs from the Workspace into my model, using a Level 2 M 
  file S function to process the test cases.

Step 2 is problematic for me, in that I cannot figure out a way to get the S-function block to accept the array-of-structs variable from the Workspace as input. I want to try avoiding the simin method (another Stackoverflow discussion, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329944/input-data-to-simulink-from-workspace)), because it seems to require representing the entire structure as a single data column, and I would like to keep the struct intact. Also tried using a Constant block with the struct array as the variable name, but that returns an 'Invalid setting for *blockname* parameter Value' for the block.

Would appreciate any suggestions for getting this set up correctly. Also open to a different method of building the model, if absolutely necessary. Thanks!

EDIT: Realized that I can import the data within the S function M file itself, using *load*. This works for the purposes of my project. However, am still interested in knowing whether a conventional solution exists for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to access the workspace, I would consider using *evalin(caller,'expression')* inside you M-file S-function:

```
mystruct = evalin('base','MyStructFromWorkspace');
/* (process mystruct) */
```

It should also do the trick.