# how to use a data from matlab as a input in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

To all MATLAB and Simulink users

I am new in matlab and simulink. I calculated a motion with time in matlab and then I would like to use it as a input data in simulink. Anyone can teach me how to do this please. Please tell more details (which block and how to set both in M and S) as I am a really really new user.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't explain it in detail, but if you have a variable in matlab (for example `myMotion` then you can just call this variable in simulink by its name. Also make sure you get some basic knowledge before asking questions to others. Try this for example: http://mercur.utcluj.ro/mobile/cursuri_oltsi/Simulink%20Tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 3):

the block you are looking for is called `From Workspace`. The easiest way to import data with it is maybe as a time series. Try using your data, and read [this](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/simulink/ug/importing-matlab-timeseries-data-to-a-root-level-input-port.html) for trouble shooting.

Also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8330468/2554157

Comment: so I dot have to write anything in matlab? for example: run the simulink or something else.

Comment: Nope. As long as you already have your variables on your workspace you don't have to write anything in MatLab. Even if the data is in a file,  you can use the 'From File'. If you need to generate the data in MatLab first, well, then you have to ;)

Comment: if I use from file what should I write down in matlab to allow simulink to read this?

Comment: Seems like you really want to write something in MatLab... but here again: you don't need to write anything, a .mat file with the data in your current folder is all you need.

Comment: My m file name is test.m  
t=1:0.1:10;
x=sin(t);
that is my file. I would like to use x as a input data in simulink. So I use 'From File' and change parameter: file name as test.mat. then I connect "From File' to "scope'. When I run it error shown:encountered in block. So how to make it work?

Comment: It sounds like you really need to learn the basics of MATLAB and Simulink first. Your file `test.m` is a MATLAB script, not a .mat file with data. You need to understand the difference between the different file types. Have a look at some of the getting started videos on http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/matlab/videos.html and  http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/simulink/examples.html.